# Class lambda callback NameError

Tags: python, class, lambda, callback, nameerror

What am I doing wrong? I want the 'refreshB' button to call the 'update' def but I get a nameError instead

```
class monitor():
    def update(self):
        print "Called"

    mon = Tk()
    mainFrame = Frame(mon)
    mainFrame.grid(row=1, column=1)

    optionFrame = Frame(mainFrame)
    optionFrame.grid(row=1, column=1)

    refreshB = ttk.Button(optionFrame, text='Refresh', command=lambda: update('self') )
    refreshB.grid(row=1, column=1)

    mon.mainloop()

monitor()


**NameError: global name 'update' is not defined**
```

I an not very familiar with Classes, is there something else I am supposed to add?

If the script above was not a class then I would use:

```
refreshB = ttk.Button(optionFrame, text='Refresh', command=lambda: update )
```

Which would works fine...

Comment: You're treating the class construct as a function. They're not the same thing. When you call a class, it doesn't execute the code inside the class. Instead, it calls the `__init__` method defined in the class and returns a new instance of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place all your initialization code inside an initialization function. Then refer to `update()` as `self.update()`.

```
    class Monitor(object):
        def update(self, event):
            print "Called"

        def __init__(self):
            self.mon = Tk()
            self.mainFrame = Frame(self.mon)
            self.mainFrame.grid(row=1, column=1)

            self.optionFrame = Frame(self.mainFrame)
            self.optionFrame.grid(row=1, column=1)

            self.refreshB = ttk.Button(self.optionFrame, text='Refresh', command=self.update)
            self.refreshB.grid(row=1, column=1)

        def run(self):
            self.mon.mainloop()

    monitor = Monitor()
    monitor.run()
```

the `update()` reference doesn't work here because it's an instancemethod and not a classmethod. Not because of the use of lambda--although I have no idea why you'd need to use a lambda function anyways. My solution involves you creating an instance of `Monitor`. This is useful because it allows you to control when the code within `Monitor` is executed. (Otherwise the code in your class body is executed at definition time. All calling `monitor()` does is return an instance of the class `monitor`--it doesn't execute the body of the code)

Comment: Ah thank you for clearing that up for me. I'm still really new to Python, only been using it for around 3 months now. I used the lambda so that I could pass objects through to the called def. Its worked for me in the past but I am just learning how to use Classes. Thanks again for your help and time :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really have code that has side effects directly in a class. You almost certainly want all that code to be in the `__init__` function instead, which gets called after your `monitor` object is created:

```
def __init__(self):
    mon = Tk()
    etc...
```

Next, `update` is an instance method so it has to be called on an object. You probably want this:

```
refreshB = ttk.Button(optionFrame, text='Refresh', command=lambda: self.update('self') )
```

But then, since your `update` method doesn't take any arguments beyond the implicit `self` argument, you actually probably want this:

```
refreshB = ttk.Button(optionFrame, text='Refresh', command=lambda: self.update() )
```

Finally, the `lambda` is useless indirection. Why don't you just give the method directly as a callback instead of wrapping it in a `lambda`?

```
refreshB = ttk.Button(optionFrame, text='Refresh', command=self.update )
```

Comment: Ah yes you are correct as well. I am using the lambda to pass arguments, I just forgot to include it in my example code. But thank you very much, your explanation is very helpful as well. If I could give you a check mark as well I would do so.